# Raycaster-intersected events for glb model children

Tags: three.js, aframe, raycasting, gltf

I am loading a glb model as shown below:

```
<a-scene>
    <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="tree" src="/path/to/tree.gltf"></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>
    <a-entity gltf-model="#tree"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

I am selecting the model by querySelector in JavaScript and attaching raycaster-intersected event to the modelEl. But this event doesn't get triggered when I hover from one child node to another child node inside the glb model. Anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 4):

This method works with primitive entities, but gltf-model entities work a little differently. That is because the gltf-model entity contains many child objects, so you need to write a custom component to get a reference to the models that you want to intersect with a raycaster and test them for intersection. In that component, you loop through all the child models using traverse, like this

```
 AFRAME.registerComponent('treeman', {
            init: function(){
                let el = this.el;
                let self = this;
                self.trees = [];              
                el.addEventListener("model-loaded", e =>{
                    let tree3D = el.getObject3D('mesh');
                    if (!tree3D){return;}    
                  //console.log('tree3D', tree3D);
                    tree3D.traverse(function(node){
                        if (node.isMesh){   
                          console.log(node);
                          self.trees.push(node);                          
                          node.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0x33aa00});
                        }
                    });
              });
```

Then you can test for intersection with a 'raycaster-intersected' event listener, like this

```
  el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersected', e =>{  
                self.raycaster = e.detail.el;
                let intersection = self.raycaster.components.raycaster.getIntersection(el);
                  console.log('click', intersection.object.name, self.mouseOverObject, 
                            intersection.object.name != self.mouseOverObject );  
                if (self.mouseOverObject != intersection.object.name){
                  intersection.object.material.emissive = new THREE.Color(0xFFFF00);
                  intersection.object.material.emissiveIntensity = 0.5; 
                } else {
                   intersection.object.material.emissive = new THREE.Color(0x000000);
                  intersection.object.material.emissiveIntensity = 0.0; 
                }                  
                  self.mouseOverObject = intersection.object.name;
              });
```

And do something on click event like this

```
 el.addEventListener('click', function(){
                console.log(self.mouseOverObject);
                if(self.mouseOverObject === "Trunk_A"){
                  //console.log('link');
                  let url = 'https://supermedium.com/supercraft/';
                  let win = window.open(url, '_blank');
                  win.focus();
                }
              });
```

here is a [glitch](https://glitch.com/~gltf-link)

Comment: +1 love the touch with the emissive highlights, yet the mouse has to leave the tree to detect a change - i'd either operate on each node separately, or do the test (oldNode != thisNode) on mousemove (expensive, i know) like [here](https://glitch.com/~gftruj-aframeselectnode)

Comment: I saw your glitch project. But it still doesn't solve my problem. When hovered on root, root was highlighted but when i hovered on other branch from root still root was highlighted instead of smaller branch which i hovered over.

Comment: @VikramHegde even in my example ? If so - what browser and OS you're on ?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski it worked on desktop but not on oculus. I wanted it in vr mode. Because of mousemove event its not working in vr mode in oculus.

Comment: lol forgot about VR. Just throw the `mousemove` stuff into the `tick` function - there is a test whether the mouse is over the model anyway. I've added a `ticktest.html` to my glitch, check it out [here](https://gftruj-aframeselectnode.glitch.me/ticktest.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help but I used laser-controls and added click event to the model. So whenever I press the trigger in vr i get the intersected object. So it solved my problem.