# A-FRAME how to update raycaster intersections?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, raycasting

I'm trying to identify the various parts of a model by clicking on them.
For now I'm able to identify them but every time that I change part I must lose focus by mouse over away from the model and then returning to the new interested part.. I'd like to find a way to make the raycaster self-update without lose focus every time. Here is my code, thank you!

```
  AFRAME.registerComponent('model1', {
            init: function(){
                let el = this.el;
                let self = this;         
                
              });
              el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersected', e =>{  
                self.raycaster = e.detail.el;
                let intersection = self.raycaster.components.raycaster.getIntersection(el); 
                  self.mousedown = intersection.object.name;
              });
              el.addEventListener('click', function(){
                console.log(self.mousedown);
              });
            }
          })
```

Comment: Check out [this glitch](https://glitch.com/~gftruj-aframeselectnode) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58804730/raycaster-intersected-events-for-glb-model-children)

Comment: thank you @PiotrAdamMilewski is the thread and glitch that I followed to obtain my actual code :) but I was missed your. Now it's ok thank you again